# DateTime Fields: is there and hidden feature / option to display seconds? Always?

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, datetime

I need to dive into precise time calculation and monitoring on the level of seconds. As it stands, Salesforce is managing internally seconds for DateTime. But - and this is very sad - the entire UI seems to cut this down to minutes...

Is there a way or a feature to enable so that Salesforce is displaying in View and Edit UIs always seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you cannot enable seconds in the standard fields and using custom fields you will run in to issues with timezone. If you are looking to measure milestones in seconds I would recommend using numeric formula fields as you can do math against datetime fields. An example being if you wanted to know how many seconds had transpired from last modified and now:

(NOW() - LastModifiedDate)*24*60*60

The numeric defaults to days so you need to multiple the number out but hours, minutes, and seconds to get the value represented.

Comment: Thanks @EricClay - I'm using workarounds like this, but unfortunately it doesn't help for the edit mode and (unless done for each and every field) it leads into an inconsistent precision of the UI.